# Mocking input using python wrapped c++ SWIG

Tags: python, c++, unit-testing, swig

I'm new to swig and python unittesting.

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I have a c++ function that requires user input.  The C++ code is wrapped into python code using SWIG.  I'm trying to use pythons unittest module to mock the input.  Ive tried mocking builtins.input and writing my own basic function in c++ that just returns a string and mocking that.

Mocking builtins.input still hangs when I get to the std::cin in the c++ code. and mocking the function that returns a string, doesnt return the mocked return_value.

My guess is for some reason I cant mock the return value of the function because its really c++ code and not true python.

Here's some example code I'm working with:

c++ I can include the header file is needed, but its really simple.

```
#include "MockTest.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

MockTest::MockTest() {}

std::string MockTest::getInput()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter you name" << std::endl;
    name = this->mockInput("hi"); //std::cin >> name;
    std::string toReturn = "Hello " + name + " person";
    return toReturn;
}

std::string MockTest::mockInput(std::string input)
{ 
    return input;
}
```

swig interface file:

```
%module MockTest
%include "std_string.i"
%include "std_vector.i"
%include "std_iostream.i"

%{
#include "MockTest.h"
%}
%include <MockTest.h>
```

python test script

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest

import MockTest


class Test(TestCase):

    @patch('builtins.input', return_value="Will")
    def test_Mocktest(self, input):
        self.assertEqual(MockTest.MockTest().getInput(), 'Hello Will person')

    @patch('MockTest.MockTest.mockInput', return_value="Will")
    def test_Mocktest2(self, mockInput):
        self.assertEqual(MockTest.MockTest().getInput(), 'Hello Will person')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I do not have the `unittest.mock` in my version of Python, but when removing the patch stuff and reintroducing the `std::cin`, everything works as expected here. I am pretty sure though that it is impossible to patch the `std::cin` of a C program using the `patch` from `unittest.mock`. You need to tell the binary (.so) file that STDIN is no longer STDIN.

Comment: How do you build your module (which are the commands)? Cause I'm getting a different error (looks like the module is incomplete). I'm using (on _Win_) _Python 3.5_, _VStudio 2015_, _SwigWin 3.0.12_.

Answer (score 1):

After spending some time out of which ~ one hour on a stupid mistake:

- The fact that the generated module was incomplete (the *linker* wasn't complaining about undefined symbols when not supplying the *MockTest* object to it)
- In the end that was generated because I forgot to add `public:` before class members in *MockTest.h* ... X:((((

and some more time investigating the real problem, I finally reached a conclusion: the problem is not because of the *C++* language (at least not directly), but it **lies in the intermediary layer(s) created by *Swig***.

#### Details

The `MockTest` class (whose `mockInput` method return value we are trying to `patch`) is defined in module `MockTest` (**!!! that is *MockTest.py* !!!**) which is automatically generated by *Swig* (the command in my case was `swig -o MockTest_wrap.cpp -python -c++ MockTest.i`). Here's its definition:

```
class MockTest(_object):
    __swig_setmethods__ = {}
    __setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: _swig_setattr(self, MockTest, name, value)
    __swig_getmethods__ = {}
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, MockTest, name)
    __repr__ = _swig_repr

    def __init__(self):
        this = _MockTest.new_MockTest()
        try:
            self.this.append(this)
        except __builtin__.Exception:
            self.this = this
    __swig_destroy__ = _MockTest.delete_MockTest
    __del__ = lambda self: None

    def getInput(self):
        return _MockTest.MockTest_getInput(self)

    def mockInput(self, input):
        return _MockTest.MockTest_mockInput(self, input)
```

As you probably guessed, **this** `mockInput` is being `patch`ed and not the one from *C++* (whose name is `MockTest_mockInput` and it's exported by the native module: `_MockTest` - the native name is `_wrap_MockTest_mockInput` defined in *MocTest_wrap.cpp*). Of course, since `getInput` calls `MockTest_getInput`, `patch`ing `mockInput` (the *Python* wrapper) has no effect (just like if you would modify its body to let's say: `return "123"`).

Here's some sample code that I prepared to better illustrate the behavior (as I mentioned in my comment, I'm using *Python 3.5.4*). Please ignore the last 3 lines of code and output til you read the next paragraph:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import MockTest


if __name__ == "__main__":
    return_value = "value overridden by `patch`"
    mock_input_arg = "argument passed to `MockTest.mockInput`"
    mock_test = MockTest.MockTest()
    with patch("MockTest.MockTest.mockInput", return_value=return_value):
        print("`mock_test.getInput()` returned: \"{}\"".format(mock_test.getInput()))
        print("`mock_test.mockInput(\"{}\")` returned: \"{}\"".format(mock_input_arg, mock_test.mockInput(mock_input_arg)))

    print("\nDon't mind the following output for now...\n")  # SAME THING about the following code

    with patch("MockTest._MockTest.MockTest_mockInput", return_value=return_value):
        print("`mock_test.getInput()` returned: \"{}\"".format(mock_test.getInput()))
        print("`mock_test.mockInput(\"{}\")` returned: \"{}\"".format(mock_input_arg, mock_test.mockInput(mock_input_arg)))
```

And the output:

> ```
> c:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q45934545>"c:\Install\x64\Python\Python\3.5\python.exe" dummy.py
> Enter you name
> `mock_test.getInput()` returned: "Hello hi person"
> `mock_test.mockInput("argument passed to `MockTest.mockInput`")` returned: "value overridden by `patch`"
>
> Don't mind the following output for now...
>
> Enter you name:
> `mock_test.getInput()` returned: "Hello hi person"
> `mock_test.mockInput("argument passed to `MockTest.mockInput`")` returned: "value overridden by `patch`"
> ```

Then I went further trying to `patch` `MockTest._MockTest.MockTest_mockInput`, but I got the same output, because I didn't `patch` `MockTest::mockInput` (from *MockTest.cpp*) but `_wrap_MockTest_mockInput` (from *MocTest_wrap.cpp*).

Below is a table with all the layers between *C++* code and *Python* for `mockInput` (for `getInput` it's exactly the same):

[image: mockInput layers]

As `getInput` calls `mockInput` (**layer 0**), there is where the `patch` should happen, but unfortunately, that's not available to *Python*.

The 1<sup>st</sup> solution that comes into my mind, is `patch`ing `getInput` (layer 1) directly (if it's used in many places).

Comment: You could create your c++ source such that you can replace the `std::cin` used with another stream, which you can control from Python

Comment: Thank you @JensMunk for the suggestion, at this point I'm not sure I know how to do that; if it will be required, I'll surely explore this approach!